# Como carregar campos da viewmodel dinamicamente no asp.net core mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-core

Tenho um relacionamento 1:N entre as classes Pessoa e Contatos. Na minha view edit, eu recebo uma viewmodel contendo uma lista de contatos. Na minha View, fiz um for no qual deverá percorrer a a lista de contatos e carregar uma row de contato dinamicamente. O problema é que não sei como fazer isso no ASP.NET CORE MVC, pois o tutorial na net que vi, ensina a fazer usando o asp.net tradicional conforme exemplo:

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Telefones.Count; i++)
 {
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Telefones[i].Id, new { @class = "hid-id" })
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Telefones[i].DDD, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control txt-ddd" } })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Telefones[i].Numero, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control txt-numero" } })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        @Html.EnumDropDownListFor(model => model.Telefones[i].Tipo, new { @class = "form-control sel-tipo" })
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-remover-telefone" data-id="@Model.Telefones[i].Id">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

}

Tentei adaptar meu projeto no asp.net core, mas o nome da view que está no marcador asp-for fica sublinhado de vermelho quebrando a compilação.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.PessoasContatosViewModel.Count(); i++)
{
   <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label asp-for="PessoaContatoViewModel[i].ContatoTipoId" class="control-label sel-contatoTipo">Tipo de Contato</label>
        <select asp-for="PessoaContatoViewModel[i].ContatoTipoId" data-plugin="selectpicker" title="Selecione uma opção" class="form-control show-tick show-menu-arrow sel-contatoTipo"></select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <label asp-for="PessoaContatoViewModel[i].Contato" class="control-label txt-contato">Contato</label>
        <input type="text" asp-for="PessoaContatoViewModel[i].Contato" class="form-control txt-contato" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="control-label">&nbsp;</label>
        <div class="checkbox-custom checkbox-default">
            <input type="checkbox" asp-for="PessoaContatoViewModel[i].ContatoPrincipal" class="ckb-contatoPrincipal" checked autocomplete="off" />
            <label asp-for="PessoaContatoViewModel[i].ContatoPrincipal class=" ckb-contatoPrincipal">Contato Principal</label>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <label asp-for="PessoaContatoViewModel[i].Detalhes" class="control-label txt-detalhes">Detalhes</label>
        <textarea asp-for="PessoaContatoViewModel[i].Detalhes" class="form-control txt-detalhes" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon btn-default btn-outline btn-remover-contato" style="margin-top: 30px;"><i class="icon wb-trash" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

}

O resultado do for deve ficar conforme na imagem, com as informações vindas da ViewModel.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe como fazer isso?

Obrigado :)

Comment: usando o `@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Telefones[i].Id, new { @class = "hid-id" })` no Core não da certo? Alguns Helpers ainda existem nele.

Comment: Ele não está funcionando dentro do for.... estranho.

Comment: Será que não é pelo fato de estar dentro de uma Partial_View não?.

Comment: Vesh, aí tem que ver com calma, mas por ser em PartialView não era para dar problemas.

Comment: Eu testei com uma View e uma PartialView. Se eu usar o razor @Html na view normal, funciona... Na PartialView não funciona.... Tenso kkkkk

Comment: O louco!!!, muito estranho isso, mas se funcionou é o que importa rsrs

Comment: Pior é que não funcionou kkkkkkk minhas telas são compostas por várias PartialViews e esta tela com os campos dinâmicos tb kkkkkkkk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vi ali nos comentários que seu for funciona na View e não na Partial certo?

Por que não roda um for fora da Partial então e deixa ela apenas como um item que o for vai adicionar?

```html
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Telefones.Count; i++)
{
      Html.Partial("_SuaPartial", Model.Telefones[i])
}
```